# how to convert normalized coordinates to pixel coordinates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, geometry, coordinates, coordinate-systems

what is the most effective way to translate from normalized coordinates (x = 0,1) (y = 0,1)

to pixel coordinates (x = 0, 1920) (x = 0, 1080)

or is there even a way to do it inside python?

i have no idea where to even start.

cause im trying to get coordinates from mediapipe's pose detection module, then tracking my mouse cursor to it

but mediapipe uses normalized coordinates and all of the mouse manipulator modules use pixel coordinates

thanks, best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, you are given two decimal numbers between 1 and 0 and asked to scale them to fit the screen.

For simplicity, let's just focus on the x axis. You have a ratio that represents how far across the screen your mouse is. For instance, 0.75 means you are 75% of the way across the screen. In order to convert to pixel coordinates, just multiply this percentage by the screen width. The same method can be applied to the y axis, just use the screen height instead of the screen width.

```
test_coord = (0.5, 0.3)

SCREEN_DIMENSIONS = (1920, 1080)


def to_pixel_coords(relative_coords):
    return tuple(round(coord * dimension) for coord, dimension in zip(relative_coords, SCREEN_DIMENSIONS))


print(to_pixel_coords(test_coord)) # prints (960, 324)
```

Comment: it works but only on ints,  and when i try to pass in my list it gives me the error: "
TypeError: type list doesn't define __round__ method", and i don't know how to fix it         here is my code in full: file:///C:/Users/m8/Desktop/offsets/pengangler.py,                                            im a beginner at this so any help would be apprechiated!

Comment: @Massive_M8: This works with more than just ints: `test_coord = (0.5, 0.3)` are floating point — so something else is wrong. Also note the link you have in your comment to your full code is to a file on your computer, which folks here on the internet cannot access.

Comment: thank you dude! i managed to figure it out